# Single term for "elephants going berserk"

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there any single term for **"Elephants going berserk"**?
  Can we say that *the elephant got wild* and started destroying whatever is in its path?
Is there any term for that? 
Hope you understand my question...

Comment: _The elephants stampeded._ (doesn't really work for a single animal)

Comment: _The elephants went ape._  :)  (I omitted the intensifier.) You might also find useful the verbs hurtle and dash.

Comment: Now, if you had said apes, instead of elephants, I'd have said: _The apes went bananas._

Comment: Only in English would an elephant go ape, an ape go bananas, and bananas just go off.

Comment: You probably meant bananas going nuts.

Comment: ..and nuts going crackers.

Comment: The elephants ran amok.

Comment: That would be a level 3 elephant alert.  We get those all the time.

Comment: **The elephants went ape, apes went bananas, bananas went nuts** This would be a lovely children book.

Answer (score 28):

The elephants *rampaged* [(M-W: Rampage:  to act or move in a wild and usually destructive way)](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rampage).

*Musth* as above is great, but only applies to males, and corresponds to a particular (sexual) context.

Comment: Yes! That word was on the tip of my tongue. All my brain mustered to spell though was rambunctious.

Answer (score 12):

Perhaps *[musth](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/musth)* is the word you are looking for:-

> An annual period of heightened aggressiveness and sexual activity in
> male elephants, during which violent frenzies occur.

One would say, "the elephant was *in musth*".

Comment: And then they say English doesn't have a word for everything!

Comment: "the elephant was in musth, and went on rampage"

Answer (score 2):

Why not say the elephants ***ran amok***? Particularly since your question appears not to ascribe this violence to libidinous impulses.

> to run about with or as if with a frenzied desire to kill

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Running_amok) offers the following description of this phrase:

> The phrase is often used in a less serious manner when describing something that is wildly out of control or causing a frenzy (e.g., a dog tearing up the living room furniture might be termed as "running amok.")

Answer (score 0):

How about "the elephant went rogue"?